# How to split string between "," using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string:

> ('Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true)

I want split this like below

- 'Vegetable'
- 'startswith'
- 'k'
- true

i have tried like below but cant get my solution

https://regexr.com/4vfpg

Comment: most languages have a split function done just for that, where you just pass the separator(a) characters, for instance comma, or comma and space. You can easily get rid of the parenthesis around the expression, Can you use it instead ? What language are you using ? Is it JavaScript as noted in regexr ?

Comment: if you have `('starts, with')` , should it parse as two strings `'starts` and `with'` ?

Comment: @Pac0, i can't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Javascript.........i cant use spilt function while using split function it consider as string

Comment: Can you have `'A \'Vegetable\' item'` inside `(...)`? Try `text.match(/'[^\\']*(?:\\[^][^\\']*)*'|[^()\s,]+/g)`, see https://regex101.com/r/O5gCHR/1/

Comment: @kumaresan_sd your question starts with `This is my string:` and then you say `i cant use spilt function while using split function it consider as string`. a string is supposed to be consider as string only. at least to me the last comment of your is not making any sense

Comment: kumaresan_sd, @Pac0 is suggesting you perform two steps: 1) remove the parentheses (e.g., `/[^()]+/`), then split the resulting string (e.g., `"'Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true"`) with `/, +/`. (Good advice, imo.)

Answer (score 1):

You can first get rid of the first opening parenthesis and the last closing one using `replace()`

The pattern `/^\((.*?)\)$/` gets an opening parenthesis at the begining, then capture everything up to (but not including) the last closing parenthesis.

Now that the string is epured, `"('Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true)"` becoming `"'Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true"`, you can use a *traditional* `split()` :

```js
console.log("('Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true)".replace(/^\((.*?)\)$/, "$1").split(', '));
```

If you want to convert the parts of the result that contains `"true"` or `"false"` as boolean value, you can `map()` the result :

```js
console.log("('Vegetable', 'startswith', 'k', true, false)".replace(/^\((.*?)\)$/, "$1")
                                                           .split(', ')
                                                           .map(elem => elem === "true" ?
                                                                     true :
                                                                     elem === "false" ?
                                                                         false :
                                                                         elem));
```

Comment: in this case it return like below `(4) ["'Vegetable'", "'startswith'", "'k'", "true"]
0: "'Vegetable'"
1: "'startswith'"
2: "'k'"
3: "true"`

Comment: but i want `true` as boolean value instead of string

Comment: @kumaresan_sd Obviously, split will return string only. If you do want the true value as boolean, iterate the output array and check `value === true`

Comment: I amusing this in more complex case, in there i can't sue like this every time

Comment: @kumaresan_sd I added an example on how you can convert the string to a boolean value

Comment: @kumaresan_sd you want to have various types as well, maybe a better option available would be to change the way your data is coming in. It's starting to quite complex just for a regexp. You might want to see if you can _serialize_ the data to something more programming-friendly, like JSON. This is smelling like [a X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).